# How zynga implemented right click in flash game?

Tags: flash, mouseevent, stage3d

I know many people asked the question about hiding the flash context menu and I know the answer is pure no.

But I wonder how zynga (in Farm Vill2 and City Ville2 which is built on stage3d) has implemented the right click event which won't show the context menu and they have implemented move and rotate feature when you right click on any object.

Is that zynga using hacks to achieve this or it is some thing hidden (undocumented) feature they have explored? which might have been introduced in stage3d (flash player 11+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature available since 11.2 player. You just need to listen for MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK.